# How to run .py file in pycharm project directory with a virtual environment in Mac terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, python-venv

Notice: I just found out that Pycharm terminal runs on x86_64 architecture and normal Mac terminal runs on arm64 architecture.
So I think this question is in the wrong direction. and I will prepare setup.py as @JoranBeasley 's advised in the comment. Thank you!

---- original question below ----

I made a python project using Pycharm with a virtual environment.
I also made my custom module "helper" in the project directory.
In "main.py", I imported my custom module "helper" and "pandas" and it works just fine when I run main.py in pycharm.
Now what I want to do is, running main.py in mac terminal.

This is what I tried to run main.py in mac terminal.

In mac terminal, I activated virtual environment with

```
username@macname ~ % source PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/activate
```

I see (venv) now so I assume I did activate virtual environment.
I guessed the next step should be including the root directory of my project because when I saw the run configuration of main.py, both of "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" and "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" were checked. I assume they are project root and the directory where the main.py in. This will make the program can find my custom module "helper".

So I set them to PYTHONPATH with

```
(venv) username@macname ~ % export PYTHONPATH=/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine
/* main.py is in engine directory */
```

and then I checked python and pip location and version with

```
(venv) username@macname ~ % which python
/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/python
(venv) username@macname ~ % which pip
/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/pip
(venv) username@macname ~ % python --version
Python 3.11.1
(venv) username@macname ~ % pip --version
pip 23.0 from /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

It looks good, so I tried to run main.py with

```
(venv) username@macname ~ % cd PycharmProjects/myProject
(venv) username@macname myProject % python engine/main.py
```

but I get this error

```
(venv) username@macname ~ % python engine/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.24.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I am stuck from this point. The strange thing is, it works just fine without error when I execute the same commands above in Pycharm terminal (with checking settings > Tools > Terminal > Activate virtualenv option).

Where should I approach this problem?

Thank you!

** Additional Info

main.py (There are only import statements and some printing)

```
import sys
import os

print("env > PYTHONPATH:", os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))
print()
print("env > PATH:", os.environ.get('PATH'))
print()
print("sys.path:", sys.path)
print()
print("sys.path:", sys.executable)
import pandas as pd  # just pandas.. version is 1.5.3
import helper  # custom module in project directory
```

I checked env variables and pip freeze on both of Mac terminal and the other Mac terminal in Pycharm. They are same.

On Mac terminal

```
(venv) usernameu@macname engine % pip freeze
altgraph==0.17.3
async-generator==1.10
attrs==22.2.0
Automat==22.10.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
bidict==0.22.1
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
chardet==5.1.0
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
cmdline==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
constantly==15.1.0
contourpy==1.0.7
cryptography==39.0.0
cssselect==1.2.0
cycler==0.11.0
dacite==1.8.0
distlib==0.3.6
dnspython==2.3.0
eventlet==0.33.3
filelock==3.9.0
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.2
fonttools==4.38.0
greenlet==2.0.1
h11==0.14.0
html-form-to-dict==2022.10.1
html5lib==1.1
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.4
incremental==22.10.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
itemadapter==0.7.0
itemloaders==1.0.6
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jmespath==1.0.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
lxml==4.9.2
macholib==1.16.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.6.3
numpy==1.24.1
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.5.3
parsel==1.7.0
Pillow==9.4.0
platformdirs==2.6.2
playwright==1.29.1
pluggy==1.0.0
Protego==0.2.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
PyDispatcher==2.0.6
pyee==9.0.4
pyinstaller==5.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.15
pyOpenSSL==23.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
PySocks==1.7.1
pytest==7.2.1
pytest-base-url==2.0.0
pytest-playwright==0.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-engineio==4.3.4
python-slugify==7.0.0
python-socketio==5.7.2
pytz==2022.7.1
PyYAML==6.0
queuelib==1.6.2
requests==2.28.2
requests-file==1.5.1
Scrapy==2.7.1
scrapy-playwright==0.0.25
selenium==4.8.0
service-identity==21.1.0
simple-websocket==0.9.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
text-unidecode==1.3
tldextract==3.4.0
trio==0.22.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
Twisted==22.10.0
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.17.1
w3lib==2.1.1
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wsproto==1.2.0
zope.interface==5.5.2
(venv) username@macname engine % python engine.py
env > PYTHONPATH: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine

env > PATH: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin

sys.path: ['/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine', '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject', '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

sys.path: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/python
/* and the error about importing pandas appears from here */
```

On Mac terminal in Pycharm

```
(venv) usernameu@macname engine % pip freeze
altgraph==0.17.3
async-generator==1.10
attrs==22.2.0
Automat==22.10.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
bidict==0.22.1
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
chardet==5.1.0
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
cmdline==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
constantly==15.1.0
contourpy==1.0.7
cryptography==39.0.0
cssselect==1.2.0
cycler==0.11.0
dacite==1.8.0
distlib==0.3.6
dnspython==2.3.0
eventlet==0.33.3
filelock==3.9.0
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.2
fonttools==4.38.0
greenlet==2.0.1
h11==0.14.0
html-form-to-dict==2022.10.1
html5lib==1.1
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.4
incremental==22.10.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
itemadapter==0.7.0
itemloaders==1.0.6
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jmespath==1.0.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
lxml==4.9.2
macholib==1.16.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.6.3
numpy==1.24.1
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.5.3
parsel==1.7.0
Pillow==9.4.0
platformdirs==2.6.2
playwright==1.29.1
pluggy==1.0.0
Protego==0.2.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
PyDispatcher==2.0.6
pyee==9.0.4
pyinstaller==5.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.15
pyOpenSSL==23.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
PySocks==1.7.1
pytest==7.2.1
pytest-base-url==2.0.0
pytest-playwright==0.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-engineio==4.3.4
python-slugify==7.0.0
python-socketio==5.7.2
pytz==2022.7.1
PyYAML==6.0
queuelib==1.6.2
requests==2.28.2
requests-file==1.5.1
Scrapy==2.7.1
scrapy-playwright==0.0.25
selenium==4.8.0
service-identity==21.1.0
simple-websocket==0.9.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
text-unidecode==1.3
tldextract==3.4.0
trio==0.22.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
Twisted==22.10.0
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.17.1
w3lib==2.1.1
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wsproto==1.2.0
zope.interface==5.5.2
(venv) username@macname engine % python engine.py
env > PYTHONPATH: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine

env > PATH: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin

sys.path: ['/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine', '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject', '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/engine', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

sys.path: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/python
```

Comment: you cannot re-use the same virtual env from a non-mac build ... it must be a new virtual env created specifically on the mac ... using its python version ... it is activating the environment (as you can see from the traceback) ...(additionally once you run activate, you should not have to explicitly set either of those environmental variables )

Comment: @JoranBeasley Sorry, I think I don't quite understand..  I made that virtual environment in Mac using pycharm. Did you mean I can't use pycharm virtual environment in Mac terminal?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Also I had to set PYTHONPATH before I run main.py in Pychcarm terminal (once I run activate). because of my custom module in project directory. Without it, I get no module named "helper(my custom module)" error.

Comment: no... it should be fine ... make sure you dont have more than one venv ... run pip freeze to see whats installed there ... its possible you messed around with the run configuration enough that numpy is loading from global site packages instead of being installed into that venv... or perhaps the venv that pycharm is using is not the same one you think you think (try printing `sys.executable` when you run it in pycharm and probably `sys.path` and `os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')`

Comment: also you should probably consider using something like poetry (or even just the normal setup.py) to make your "custom library" into an actual library that just works

Comment: @JoranBeasley I checked them on both of mac terminal, pycharm mac terminal. but they printed the same path and same packages. The pandas version is same on both 1.5.3. I added main.py code and the result in the post. Originally I wanted to run the code from other language as subprocess. (in Go lang) So before that, I tried to test if it works on mac terminal.. but I started to think it was a bad idea..